# c() function in javascript, meaning?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was looking through the source code of a web page, and I came across this JavaScript:

```
    function fsb329142055() {
      var b=new Array(57,50,102,50,52,99,50,53,52,56,102,98,102,98,101,102,101,49,53,61,101,99,110,57,111,78,109,54,114,111,56,48,102,38,100,53,100,53,48,50,55,52,49,55,57,50,52,51,98,53,56,61,100,99,100,55,73,116,97,53,53,115,105,108,100,55,116,105,104,38,53,116,104,38,103,104,105,102,61,61,98,110,111,105,116,99,97,38,112,50,51,104,112,46,116,50,104,99,103,105,56,102,51,61,98,50,53,51,49,56,97,101,57,116,54,49,63,100,52,97,100,112,104,97,112,46,116,115,102,56,51,105,108,98,52,116,52,53,105,104,100,97,47,101,98,98,52,100,97,57,99,99,54);
      var p=new Array(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);       
      window.location = c(b,p);
      return false;
    }
```

This function is called here:

```
<a href="/hitlist.php?tab=fight.php&amp;action=fight&amp;hitlistId=329142055&amp;formNonce=1eb542f92c248ffbfe59680dd774b58dc7a55d75&amp;h=284e4fe4946e6fb8af3a662f4583454eebc8bd23" onclick="return fsb329142055();">
             <div class="fightActionInner"><div class="fightActionInnerInner">Attack</div>    </div>
           </a>
```

Specifically, I'm wondering what the `window.location = c(b,p);` is.

People are saying it is a function, but I dont see it anywhere in the source code:

`

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.storm8.com/im/css/global.css?v=330"/> 


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.storm8.com/im/js/global.js?v=330"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.storm8.com/im/js/equipment.js?v=330"></script>    <title>Add the Hit List</title>
    <script>
      function s8Ajax(url) {
        window.location.href = url;
      }
    </script>
    </head>

<body style="; width: 100%;" class="portrait" data-promo-button="">
<div id="fb-root"></div>




  <div id="contentParent">
    <div id="contentChild" style="">
      <div id="SCROLL_CONTENT"><div id="scrollContentChild"><div>

<div id="overlay" class="dialogOverlay"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.isAndroid = false;
        window.isFacebook = false;
    </script>
  <div id="topBar" class="topBar"><div class="topBarBg"></div><div id="inner-topbar"><a href="/bank.php?formNonce=81668c46988c486ed2d1d0b1f7e31f16d41c093c&setTab1Badge=&h=da793b290e598f2e0823e93dbab769b0736a7557"><div class="cashTopArea">
        <span class="topBarCash">$<span id="cashCurrent" style="white-space:nowrap">138,136,907</span></span>
      </div>
      <div id="cashTimerDiv" class="cashBottomArea"><span style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal;"><span>+<span style="white-space: nowrap;">255,350</span></span> in </span><span id="cashType" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;">59:05</span></div></a><div class="levelTopArea">
          <div class="levelBgTopArea"></div>
          <div class="levelFrontTopArea"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="/profile.php?formNonce=81668c46988c486ed2d1d0b1f7e31f16d41c093c&setTab1Badge=&h=dc3aa8ea9e33fff4ea763e4556ad5e0ca2718a3b">31</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="levelBottomArea">
        Level
        </div><div class="levelBarTopArea">
             <div class="levelBar" style="width:90px">
             <div class="bgLevelBar" style="width:90px"><div id="expBar" class="frontLevelBar" style="width:36px">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="levelBarBottomArea">
        Exp: <span id="expText">5793/5993</span>
        </div>
        <a href="/favor.php?"><div class="energyAreaContainer"><table class="statTable"><tr><td class="statTableIcon"><div></div></td>
          <td class="statTableInBetween"></td>
          <td class="statTableInfo">
            <div class="statTopArea">
            <span id="energyCurrent" class="statEmphasis">75</span> / <span id="energyMax">75</span></div>        
            <div id="energyTimerDiv" class="statBottomArea"><span id="energyType" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;">Energy</span></div></td></tr></table></div></a>
        <a href="/hospital.php?"><div class="healthAreaContainer"><table class="statTable"><tr><td class="statTableIcon"><div></div></td>
          <td class="statTableInBetween"></td>
          <td class="statTableInfo">
            <div class="statTopArea">
            <span id="healthCurrent" class="statEmphasis">100</span> / <span id="healthMax">100</span></div>        
            <div id="healthTimerDiv" class="statBottomArea"><span id="healthType" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;">Health</span></div></td></tr></table></div></a>
        <a href="/favor.php?"><div class="staminaAreaContainer"><table class="statTable"><tr><td class="statTableIcon"><div></div></td>
          <td class="statTableInBetween"></td>
          <td class="statTableInfo">
            <div class="statTopArea">
            <span id="staminaCurrent" class="statEmphasis">5</span> / <span id="staminaMax">5</span></div>        
            <div id="staminaTimerDiv" class="statBottomArea"><span id="staminaType" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;">Stamina</span></div></td></tr></table></div></a></div><script>
        setTopBarTimerData({"cash":{"page":"\/bank.php?","text":"Cash","timeLeft":3545,"value":138136907,"maxValue":999999999999,"rate":3600,"update":255350},"energy":{"page":"\/favor.php?","text":"Energy","timeLeft":-1,"value":75,"maxValue":"75","rate":240,"update":1},"health":{"page":"\/hospital.php?","text":"Health","timeLeft":-1,"value":100,"maxValue":"100","rate":180,"update":1},"stamina":{"page":"\/favor.php?","text":"Stamina","timeLeft":-1,"value":5,"maxValue":"5","rate":120,"update":1},"experience":{"width":90,"value":"5793","previousLevelValue":5658,"nextLevelValue":5993}});      
        createTopBarTimer();
      </script></div></div><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.storm8.com/im/css/bounty.css?v=330"/>
<div class="section">
<div class="sectionHeader">
Add "Raͭgͪnͤa͠rok" to the Hit List</div>
<div class="sectionBar"></div><div class="sectionContent">

      <script>
        function fsb10213841(x) {
          var b=new Array(49,100,50,100,100,48,98,101,54,49,102,56,55,101,52,99,56,56,57,51,54,52,49,99,56,102,49,54,100,54,54,52,49,49,56,99,61,101,99,110,48,111,78,57,51,99,38,109,104,61,114,50,50,51,111,102,38,57,52,49,52,51,57,102,56,51,49,98,51,50,50,51,57,48,49,61,51,48,48,54,100,105,95,53,57,116,51,97,57,99,97,115,56,57,54,105,54,108,51,116,105,51,49,49,101,48,99,104,54,100,63,112,104,112,46,121,116,110,117,111,98);
          var p=new Array(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);       
          var bountyForm = document.getElementById('bountyForm');
          bountyForm.action = c(b,p) + x;
          return true;
        }
      </script>
    <form id="bountyForm" method="post" onsubmit="return fsb10213841('373');" action="/bounty.php?hitlist_id=10213841&formNonce=81668c46988c486ed2d1d0b1f7e31f16d41c093c&h=284e4fe4946e6fb8af3a662f4583454eebc8bd23">
<ul>
<li>The minimum bounty amount is <span style="white-space: nowrap;">$10,000</span>.</li>
<li>A 15% fee will be charged to safeguard the bounty.</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="bountyLabel">Bounty Amount:</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="bountyValue" size=25 class="medTextField">    <br/>
    <div style="height:6px">&nbsp;</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Place Bounty" name="action" class="btnMed btnBroadcast">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div></div><br/><br/><script> window.onload = function() { window.location.href = "#&setTab0Badge=&changeApplicationBadge=0&setTab4Badge=1";}</script></div></body></html>
```

Comment: That's a function that is not defined in the code snippet you posted

Comment: The developer who made that web page must have defined that function somewhere else in their code.

Comment: You're going to need to do some more research to figure that one out. In the developer console of chrome you might be able to simply figure out what c(b,p) returns by passing the arguments in manually and putting the return else where.

Comment: @grandinero I have updated it with the source code. No sign of any function like that.

Comment: `function c` is defined in `global.js`

Comment: @Carl I can't believe I didn't think to look there. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the HTML you provided, you'll see the following tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.storm8.com/im/js/global.js?v=330"></script>
```

Go to http://static.storm8.com/im/js/global.js?v=330 and you'll find the following function definition:

```
function c(b,p) {
    a='';s=String.fromCharCode;
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) {if(p[i])a=s(b[i])+a;else a+=s(b[i]);}
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is located in the included javascript files in head

http://static.storm8.com/im/js/global.js?v=330

line no: 411 and function code is as follow:

```
function c(b,p) {
    a='';s=String.fromCharCode;
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) {if(p[i])a=s(b[i])+a;else a+=s(b[i]);}
    return a;
}
```